# how to get RadioButtons Id using HashTable and Key from HasTable

Tags: java, android, hashtable

i m not much Familiar with HashTable and and using HashTable to make RadioButtons Dynamically. i m able to make RadioButtons using HashTable but not able to get RadioButtons id and Error is showing **java.lang.NullPointerException**

here is code that i m using

```html
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            
    final   Hashtable<Integer, String> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, String>(); 
    ht.put(1, "sachin"); 
    ht.put(2, "sehwag"); 
    ht.put(3, "dhoni"); 
    final Enumeration<Integer> values = ht.keys(); 
             
      while (values.hasMoreElements()) 
      {  str = (Integer) values.nextElement(); 
         System.out.println(str + ":" + ht.get(str));
         RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButtonView.setText(ht.get(str));
            radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
          } 
             
           
     Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // checking Correct Answer
      RadioButton selectedButton=   (RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()); 
      String q_ans = selectedButton.getText().toString();
      int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
     }
       });
```

Here  is Error showing in CatLog

```css
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.example.testing.HashMaps$1.onClick(HashMaps.java:73)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest how to get the RadioButtons id and Key from HashTable
so i will able to move Further
thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Key from hashmap use `Key.set()` for more information look on this link [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) Example

```html
Set<String> keys = h.keySet();
// Loop over String keys.
for (String key : keys) {
   System.out.println(key);
}
```

can you please tell me for which purpose you are getting RadioButtons id?
After that i can give you exact solution that will best suit for your question
thanks

Comment: thansk for code but still not able to get the RadioButton id